# Access Oracle 11g installed inside VirtualBox Guest from Ubuntu Host

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g, virtualbox

My config :

```
Host : Ubunty 14.04
Guest: Win7 Pro x64
```

My guest network type : Bridged.
Guest Ip : 192.168.0.250

I've oracle 11g installed in the Guest. When i click the

> Get Started With Oracle Database 11g Express Edition

it opens the link

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950:1:3510857550509522

in the guest browser (Chrome).

When I am trying to access this url from Ubuntu(Host) machine, I cannot reach it.
How ever, when I ping the ip (mentioned above) from the host, I am getting  reply from the guest.

So what am I doing wrong ? And what needs to be done to use my Guest as a DB Server for my host ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Firewall was blocking the port 8080. Allowed that, and everything is working now.